# Docker is not respecting permissions inside the container, why?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This might been asked before or even discussed but I can't find anything to help me on this one. I am running `Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5` and `docker-compose version 1.25.0-rc4, build 8f3c9c58` both in Windows and both are Edge versions. My project `Dockerfile` looks like follow:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev \
        git \
        unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.7.2 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini" \
    && mv /var/www/html /var/www/localproj \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php
COPY --from=composer:1.9 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY docker/apache/bootstrap.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-app-entrypoint
WORKDIR /var/www/localproj
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-app-entrypoint"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

And the `bootstrap.sh` file is this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

>&2 echo "Running composer install"
php -dxdebug.remote_enable=0 /usr/bin/composer install -n
>&2 echo "Composer install complete."

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/localproj

exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

Each time I start the container I end up with the following error:

```
localproj        | Script php bin/console cache:clear returned with error code 1
localproj        | !!  [04-Nov-2019 16:27:26 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/localproj/var/cache/local/annotations.map): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/localproj/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php on line 377
localproj        | !!
localproj        | !!  In Filesystem.php line 290:
localproj        | !!
localproj        | !!    Cannot rename "/tmp/removed-ids.phpbOhMis" to "/var/www/localproj/var/cache/
localproj        | !!    local/Container1LP3QEI/removed-ids.php".
```

Clearly something with permissions is wrong. I tried this "nasty" (if you know a better one please add it here) solution but it did not work either for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mkdir /var/www/localproj/var/cache
mkdir /var/www/localproj/var/log
chmod -R 777 /var/www/localproj/var

chown -R root:root /var/www/localproj

>&2 echo "Running composer install"
php -dxdebug.remote_enable=0 /usr/bin/composer install -n
>&2 echo "Composer install complete."

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/localproj

exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

Could be this caused by the Docker Edge version? (I don't think so but is worthy to ask). What I am missing here? Why permissions are not allowing PHP to copy files over `/var/www/localproj/var` directory?

Comment: Somehow i'm missing something inside here.
How does the php data get into the container/image?
Why don't you build your data in a multistage dockerfile? (Then you don't have to run composer in your real container on start time. Save some time to start the container. Usually you don't want to wait until build is done. Especially, if composer fails for any reason)

Comment: @ManuelPolacek I have omitted some information because is not relevant to the issue. The code (I assume this is what you mean by PHP data) is mount through a `docker-compose.yml` file. What do you mean by build data in a multistage Dockerfile? What is the purpose of that if I need to run `composer install` several times during develop process? TBH I am not following you on this one

Comment: So this is just the container for development and you mount your code into the container. BTW did you tried your image before by adding the source code instead of adding a mount? If this should work your mount doesn't work because of you OS directory permissions, I think.